change position of chrome password tooltip- in css / html
Is there any way i can change the position of this browser tooltip to left or top as it is on top of my website's texts? Or if i can make my text appear on top of that tooltip? Are there any workarounds to deal with this? Thanks!
This tooltip always appears whenever I focus on the password field. And those instructions on right are designed to only appear when the password field is focused and disappear when the focus is taken away. So there is no way to hide that tooltip without taking the focus away from the field, which also hides the instructions. The only way that tooltip hides in focus is by pressing the esc key, so maybe if we can simulate esc key or something it may work? please let me know if it is possible. Thanks!
I am using angular if that is helpful.

